# How to i move the text to the left side of the container?

Tags: html, css

I've tried margin 0 auto in the css but it didn't seem to work, i'm not quite sure what i'm doing wrong, could anyone help me? I would like to move the text to touch  the left side of the container because as of now it is in the middle of the container. The text I'm talking about is the text in the p tags, which are the email, Facebook, instagram, and twitter. Thanks for taking the time to help. Have a good day!

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/yourCustom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" style="color:#000000">Paulo Pinzon-Iradian</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="work.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <p style="font-size:24px;"></p>ppinzon-iradian@hotmail.com</p>
        </br>
        <p><a>Facebook</a></p>
        <p><a>Instagram</a></p>
        <p><a>Twitter</a></p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.navbar-default{
    background: #fff;
    margin-top:3.5%;
    border:0px;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
}

ul, li, a
{
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000000;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
    border:0px;
}

.col-xs-6
{
    margin-top:1.5%;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.row
{
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.jumbotron
{
    background: #fff;
    border:0px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Which text? Mention it

Comment: the text within the p tags, which is the email, Facebook, instagram and twitter

Comment: It is better to use .well class if  you really do not want much padding. why use .jumbotron when same (as u needed) can be done by .well class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's a large padding surrounding the `p` elements. To fix that without overriding it using bootstrap class, add new class `no-padding` or something then override it on the css targeting that new class.

e.g.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron no-padding">
    <p style="font-size:24px;"></p>ppinzon-iradian@hotmail.com</p>
    </br>
    <p><a>Facebook</a></p>
    <p><a>Instagram</a></p>
    <p><a>Twitter</a></p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.container .jumbotron.no-padding
{
    background: #fff;
    border:0px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7up0efcg/)

Comment: @ppinzon Great! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The elements you want to remove the margin are inside a `.jumbotron` element, this is styled by bootstrap and will add those margins/paddings. Check the docs for [jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
```

You can either override the styles by adding `!important` in your styles (bust me after the bootstrap styles), or use another bootstrap component other thant jumbotron.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean text in `.jumbotron` class, you can simply remove `padding-left` in

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container .jumbotron, .container-fluid .jumbotron {
        padding-right: 60px;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

or simply remove it

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container .jumbotron, .container-fluid .jumbotron {
        padding-right: 60px;
    {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left padding from the `jumbotron` container, either through your css page or inline styling.

Example:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="padding-left:0px;">
// your content here
</div>
```

or (using css):

```
.jumbotron {
     padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mwatz122/614wjpjh/